# Using Node's fs module in Angular v9 project embedded in Electron / Capacitor cross-platform environment

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, capacitor

I'm facing issues when trying to import the Node.js (v12.13) file system module fs into Angular components/services *.ts files with "import * as fs from 'fs';". I know normally you are not supposed to do that in a web application accessing any file system, but I'm using Angular in an Electron (v7) context, also together with a Capacitor cross-platform development context, such acting as regular desktop application. I'm receiving errors like "Cannot find module 'fs'" or "Module not found, can't resolve 'fs'" I've seen similar Angular+Electron project setups where in Angular classes fs is imported and used in that way, I just can't figure out what exact configurations need to be added to a 'normally' setup Angular project to avoid build errors and make fs usable during runtime when started as electron app.

Comment: Do you have `nodeIntegration: true` in your BrowserWindow `webPreferences` option? You won't be able to access node APIs from the renderer otherwise. https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v7.0.0/docs/api/browser-window.md#new-browserwindowoptions

Comment: yes, it's set to true. that alone is not doing the trick

Comment: Did you solve this? Could you post more information, like copying your *.module.ts and components' imports?...